# Comparison of IPEndPoint objects not working

Tags: c#

I have an IPEndPoint a and b, whose IPAddress and Port are exactly the same, but the == operator is on the IPEndPoint not returning true. To make things even stranger, I tried to circumvent the problem by simply comparing the IPAddress and Port individually and it is STILL not returning true.

Has anyone encountered this before? If so, I am all ears to performant solutions. We have collections of as many as 10k IPEndPoints and are querying into them via LINQ (PLINQ pretty soon).

Comment: I have not tried this, but check this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016471/how-to-compare-ip-addresses).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzszfbba.aspx) and [IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s128tyf6.aspx) don't implement the == operator. By default, the == operator compares if the two objects are the same reference, not if they represent the same value.

Use the [IPAddress.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytw09x9b.aspx) / [IPEndPoint.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7a45x6z.aspx) methods instead.

Comment: That works. However, I thought that if I were checking the actual reference, I would use Object.ReferenceEquals(); Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IPAddress does not define an overload for == however it does override Object.Equals, so your equality check should be:

```
public static bool AreEqual(IPEndpoint e1, IPEndpoint e2)
{
    return e1.Port == e2.Port && e1.Address.Equals(e2.Address);
}
```

If you are using linq, it is probably a good idea to create your own `IEqualityComparer<IPEndpoint>` to encapsulate this, since various linq methods take one to compare items.

Comment: IPEndPoint overrides Object.Equals as well.

Comment: This code is unnecessary because [IPEndPoint.Equals() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7a45x6z.aspx) already implements the same check:
`public override bool Equals(object comparand)
{ return comparand is IPEndPoint && ((IPEndPoint)comparand).m_Address.Equals(this.m_Address) && ((IPEndPoint)comparand).m_Port == this.m_Port;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare HashCodes...

```
IPEndPoint a = ....
IPEndPoint b = ....

if(a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()){
...
}
```

it works ^^