# Strange .Net behavior on IPAddress equals

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to compare ip addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016471/how-to-compare-ip-addresses)

Please, tell me someone, why this code (.Net 4.0):

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
if (ip == IPAddress.Any) Console.WriteLine("any"); 
else Console.WriteLine("Not any");
Console.WriteLine(IPAddress.Any.ToString());
```

Show me next results in console:
Not any
0.0.0.0

Comment: This is not a duplicate to the referenced question. The referenced question asks how to compare two IPAddresses for equality. This question remarks that IpAddress.Operato== behaves differently than IPAddress.Equals(IpAddress). MSDN itself advises when override Equals to  also overrid operator== (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `Equals` method.

`if (ip.Equals(IPAddress.Any))`

Comment: +1 and the reason is simple `operator ==` is not overloaded in IPAddress class

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

According to MSDN (see **Overriding Operator ==** section):

> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by
>   determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference
>   types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this
>   functionality.

As it appears, IPAddress does not override == operator and you compare references of two different instances. As it was mentioned already, you should use `.Equals()` function to compare two `IPAdress` instances.

Comment: _IPAddress does not override == operator_...
but why? they done it for other BLC

Answer (score 0):

[`IPAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) is a static readonly field. `IPAddress` is a class so when you try to check equality, they checked by their *reference*. That's why you had an error. Try wity `Equals()` method.

> Provides an IP address that indicates that the server must listen for
>   client activity on all network interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

For reasons best known to Microsoft, the framework evaluates `IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0")` using their objectIDs rather than their values when you ask for an object-level comparison. That is, you're asking whether the two are the same object (i.e. internal pointers to the stored values) rather than the same *value*.

However, you can do what you're looking for using the `Equals()` method:

```
IPAddress ipMine = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
IPAddress ipAny = IPAddress.Any;

Console.WriteLine(ipMine == ipAny);         // will output false
Console.WriteLine(ipMine.Equals(ipAny));    // will output true
```

The framework's built-in implicit handling of basic objects (int, float, string etc) as primitives at the right times spoils us sometimes, and it's always worth remembering that for complex types, .NET will, by default, handle them as references unless the author implements operator methods explicitly. In the above case, MS decided it was more useful for the default behaviour to be comparison by ref, but `Equals` should always do a value-based comparison, so you're all good.

Comment: This makes no sense: "For reasons best known to Microsoft, the framework evaluates IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0") using their objectIDs". The `IPAddress.Parse()` method has no bearing on the behavior of `operator==`, nor the `Equals()` method. Parse is simply one of several ways of creating IPAddress instances, each of which results in the exact same behavior when performing comparisons.